# Can I set the Timings of the Revmob Ads and the Chartboost ads so that it appears after my Splash Screen?

Tags: android, admob, splash-screen, revmob, chartboost

In my app ,when my splash screen appears along with that the revmob as well as the chartboost ad also appears.I want it to appear in order like 1---> Splash Screen  2----> Revmob Ads 3----> Chartboost ads.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I work in iOS, not android, but the concept should be similar. You would need to use the delegates so that you could display the second after the first is dismissed. I didn't use revmob, so you need to see their documentation for the delegates, but if you wanted the reverse order (chartboost->revmob), one way to do it would be:

```
- (void)didDismissInterstitial:(NSString *)location 
{
    //this is fired after a chartboost interstitial is closed
    //so you set the code to display the other starting from here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yazan ,for replying